# Testing a prime number with loop 1: sqrt(x)

Tags: r, loops

I am learning about loops and I have this code to check if a number is prime or not, but doesn't work. Where is the bug?

```
x <- 7
y <- seq(1,sqrt(x),by=1)
for(i in 1: sqrt(x)){
 if(y[x%%y == 0]) {
   print("FALSE")
 }else{
   print("TRUE")
 }
}
```

This gives me the right solution, but it repeats the answer as many times as number of elements in i. Also I would like to ask how to use function inside a for with if:

```
i <- c(1: sqrt(x))
y3 <- x%%i == 0
y4 <- y3[-1] 
for(value in i){
  if(y4 == FALSE) {
    print("TRUE")
  }else{
    print("FALSE")
  }
}
```

version 3, gives me the solution but for evey element in i:

```
x <- 107
i <- c(1: sqrt(x))
y3 <- c(x%%i == 0)
y4 <- y3[-1] 
for(value in i){
  if(all(y4==F)) {
    print("TRUE")
  }else{
    print("FALSE")
  }
}
```

Comment: why you need for loop?

Comment: is it absolutely necessary to use a loop?

Comment: yes it is neccesary

Comment: Well, to start, you never use `i` at all. I would take the time to really debug this and check the values of each object at each step of the loop

Comment: I added another version, which uses i, but still doesn't work.

Comment: vr. 3 doesn't work properly, gives more than 1 answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you must use a loop, the following code will work:

```
x <- 7
y <- seq(1, ceiling(sqrt(x)), by=1)

# is.factor is a vector which checks whether each element in y is a factor or not
# initialize to F
is.factor = F

# Start at y = 2 because 1 will be a factor
for(i in 2:length(y) ){

  # Check whether current value in vector is a factor of x or not
  # if not a factor, set value in index to F, otherwise set to T 
  ifelse( x%%y[i] != 0, is.factor[i] <- F, is.factor[i] <- T)

  # If we are at the last element in y, print a result
  if(i == length(y)){

    # check if we have any factors. 
    # if we have any factors (i.e. any index in is.factor vector is T), then number is not prime
    ifelse( any(is.factor), print("FALSE"), print("TRUE") ) 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this-

```
check_prime <- function(num) {
    if (num == 2) {
        TRUE
    } else if (any(num %% 2:(num-1) == 0)) {
        FALSE
    } else { 
        TRUE
    }
}

> check_prime(7)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I am leaning about loops in R